How do you access a list of a users Quick Favorites?
I am trying to add my quick favorites to a separate panel, but I can't find any way to access the list of Quick Favorites. I've read it's in user preferences, but I can't find how to target that or the list using bpy.

Hello ! AFAIK this isn't accessible to the python API unfortunately...

blender/source/blender/editors/interface
/interface_context_menu.cc in ui_popup_context_menu_for_button() explicitly mentions the "Quick Favorites" and from there you get to Blender\4.2\scripts\presets\keyconfig\keymap_data\blender_default.py in line 702: "Quick menu and toolbar" and then it looks to me like that is where the journey ends. I do not think the data of the Quick Favorites is accessible. It's probably stored somewhere in the RNA, but not in the file specific part. You can try to find more: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ablender%2Fblender%20SCREEN_MT_user_menu&type=code

Default hotkey Q calls menu SCREEN_MT_user_menu in most areas.
See Preferences > Keymap > Window > Quick Favorites
The menu can be inserted into a panel with layout.menu_contents('SCREEN_MT_user_menu')
import bpy

class TEST_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PT_Panel'
    bl_label = "Quick Favorites"                      
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "TEST"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.menu_contents('SCREEN_MT_user_menu') # Quick Favorites Menu

bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_Panel)

(tested 3.67, 4.11)
